# .load() for loading htm in htm with parameter

Tags: javascript

In Index.html I have:

```
  <head> 

  <script> 
    $(function(){ $(".myDIV").load("page.htm?city=London"); });
  </script>

  </head>

 <body>
     <div class="myDIV"></div>
 </body>
```

everything works except parameter ?city=London

I mean page.htm is opening inside index.htm but parameter city is not visible. 
Should it works?

In page.htm I have

```
<script>

var getUrlParameter = function getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    var sPageURL = decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)),
        sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&'),
        sParameterName,
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) {
        sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');

        if (sParameterName[0] === sParam) {
            return sParameterName[1] === undefined ? true : sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
};

</script>
```

and finally

```
<div class="city"></div>
<script>
  var cityVar= getUrlParameter('city');
  $('.city').html(cityVar);
</script>
```

Comment: `load` function takes the query string of your current url.  
Try access `index.html?city=somethingElse` and see what happens.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368864/how-to-access-url-parameters-sent-to-div-via-jquery-load This works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try by passing querystring as second argument:

```
$(".myDIV").load("page.html", { city: 'London' });
```

Comment: It doesnt help. 
[link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_load.asp)

Here it is written: URL - Required. Specifies the URL you wish to load.
So if my required url is page.htm?city=London I think its good syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you try to retrieve the query string using javascript and not in server side.

While server will see the query string that you pass inside `load`, javascript will see the current url.

For example, you can simply do something like:

```
<script>
   var city = "<?php echo $_GET['city']; ?>";
</script>
```

Comment: in page.html

`<script>
  var cityVar = getUrlParameter('city');
  alert(cityVar);
</script>`

I did this in page.html and it's loaded in index.html but parameter city is undefined.

Comment: Yes, this is because you try to retrieve it via javascript, which access the current url ot *the page*, not the url which you pass by `load` function.

Comment: your answer with `"<?php echo $_GET['city']; ?>";` It should be in page.htm?

Comment: Yes, this is the page which you are interested in extracting `city` variable from the query string.